# Recommendations for Java Web App using Netbean with Struts 2 implementation

Tags: java

My team is starting on a Java Web Application consisting of html, jsp and java servlets.

We're thinking of using frameworks and we've decided on Struts 2.

Tried googling but few resources came up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What made you choose Struts 2 over Spring? When making the decision did you consider how easy the framework would be to learn, or how much information/support is available in the community?

Answer (score 0):

I see. We were given the choice of Struts 2, Struts 1, Spring and JSF.

My team is used to Java programming with output to MS Dos. We're trained in object orientation and data management with sql.

We would love to use a framwork to ease up our coding time (e.g: code the manager/objects class files).

I'll definitely check out spring. By default, netbeans supports the Struts 1.3, JSF plug-in.

Comment: You can find a Netbeans plugin here: http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=23467 , that supports Struts 2 very well.